# Parsing url that requires to be logged in with Python

Tags: python, cookies, authentication

I am trying to read an HTML page with python 2.7. The URL of this web page is, for example, a home page that i have logged in.
The problem is that when i am trying to read this URL with python, the results are these from the login page and not these from the home page that i am logged in.
Is there anything i can do with cookies or something like that?
I don't want to login form python.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want to login from python you should stick with it. There's no other way you could do that. Either you're using requests, urllib or your browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do in these cases is this:

1. Open Chrome Dev Tools, to the Networking tab
2. Reload the page
3. Right click the relevant request and click copy > copy as cURL
4. Use a converter [like this](http://curl.trillworks.com/) to convert the cURL to python requests code.  Note that this uses the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/#install) package, which you'll have to install from pip: `pip install requests`.
5. Now you have python code that mimics the request the browser made, with all request headers and cookies! Since sessions are stored in cookies, this means your requests from python will be logged in and ready to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot Christopher, that was really helpful.

Comment: My pleasure! If an answer here solves your problem, please mark it as accepted if you don't mind :)